# which database uses this structure of files and directories?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm trying to read data from a database that I don't know and that has the following structure:

```
cur
|
|
---- FILE ----
|             rs_pers.dat
|             rs_pers.fmt
|             rs_pers.idx
|             ..............
|             WS_FTP.LOG
|
---- red7-----
|             77008
|             .........
|
---- sys------
|             db.DAT
|             db.idx
|             ........
|
|
cee_ap
name.idx
name.dat
...........
isam.log
tmpout3384.txt
```

Does anyone know which database is and how to read it ?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think WS_FTP.LOG is a real data file.  It's from an FTP client.

Comment: Could be a C-ISAM implementation. Are the .fmt files human readable?

Comment: Yes, fmt file contails: TODAY FORMAT FILE
Created using TODAY 8.02.00
# Created on date: 10/10/18, time: 08:58:37, by user: guest   
# Application: xxxx    , version: xxx    , version number=0

TODAY filename:   xxxxxxxx
File type:        XISAM           
Default record:   1
Op sys filename:  usr/file/xx_xxxx
Database name:    
Record name list: xx_xxx 
Index name list:  xx_xxx

Comment: Could be an old DOS database such as FoxPro, dBase or Clipper.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly it was created in the TODAY programming language (itself created by TodaySystems).  TODAY is a very old (20 years?) language that doesn't appear to have been widely used, though it seems to form the core of the 4GL BuilderProfessional development environment.

In answer to "how do I read it?", you should be able to find the file format in the .FMT file and then read from the .DAT (which is a flatfile) according to that format.

I've recently come across a TODAY app myself and am keen to find any documentation for it!

JC